# Profile Back using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I'm using a simple copy-item to back up a user profile on my work's domain. And I'm using Task Scheduler to run this script, which works perfectly when I'm logged in but I want it to work when I'm logged out and GPO prevents local user or admin accounts. Is there another way to accomplish this?

Comment: Try running the task as system?

Comment: It needs to be able to access our SAN to actually put the "back up" (copy) there

Comment: "GPO prevents local user or admin accounts"  Care to explain that?  What policy is it?  Is your account lacking the logon as a service right?

Comment: I don't see how that's relevant, but my supervisor has informed me that GPO deletes Local accounts so I can't use those cridintials